# SQL-Trigger: Create row if row doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that updates a row in another table on an insert. The last part works but if there is no row with that id, I want to create a row for that id before adding to it.

But I get a #1064 error: 'resource_xpEvents FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM resource_xp '

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT resource_xpEvents FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM resource_xp WHERE userId = NEW.userId) THEN
    INSERT INTO resource_xp (userId)
    VALUES (NEW.userId);
END IF;

UPDATE resource_xp
    SET xp = xp + new.delta
    WHERE userId = new.userId

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT ON resource_xpEvents FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM resource_xp WHERE userId = NEW.userId) THEN
    INSERT INTO resource_xp (userId)
    VALUES (NEW.userId);
END IF;

UPDATE resource_xp
    SET xp = xp + new.delta
    WHERE userId = new.userId;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

If you want to experiment:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT ON resource_xpEvents FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    REPLACE INTO resource_xp (userId,xp) values (NEW.userId,xp+new.delta);

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

which is more readable, but performance are worse.

Comment: you get the error when you try to install the trigger ?

Comment: My bad. Another error: Error in syntax at 'END' on line 12

Comment: Because you are missing a ; at the end of the update statement.

Comment: This problem is an UPSERT, and MySQL has a better way of dealing with it than this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using MySQL's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax here.  First, if the `userId` column is not already unique, make it unique:

```
ALTER TABLE resource_xp ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (userId);
```

Then, instead of trying to do a separate conditional insert and update statement, just do the following single statement:

```
INSERT INTO resource_xp (userId)
VALUES (NEW.userId)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE xp = xp + NEW.delta
```

Here is code for the full suggested trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT resource_xpEvents FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO resource_xp (userId)
    VALUES (NEW.userId)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE xp = xp + NEW.delta
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```